# /boot is full on /sda1. I need to add unused 17g partition from /sdb6?

Tags: 14.04

I have an unused partition on /sdb6 (my error) that I need to merge into /sda1 to extend /boot. /boot is full and I have a crypt-luks fs on /sda2, but I don't see the button that allows me to provide the screenshot from GParted.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ea707

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758  1953523711   976510977    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5          501760  1953523711   976510976   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2dffccca

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2          206848   195086626    97439889+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       195088382   976771071   390841345    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5       195088384   939128831   372020224   83  Linux
/dev/sdb6       939130880   976771071    18820096   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/mapper/crypt1: 999.9 GB, 999945142272 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121569 cylinders, total 1953017856 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/crypt1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 987.1 GB, 987070726144 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 120004 cylinders, total 1927872512 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 12.8 GB, 12826181632 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1559 cylinders, total 25051136 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ mount
/cow on / type overlayfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sr0 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ubuntu)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow            8.8G  111M  8.7G   2% /
udev            8.8G   12K  8.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G  1.4M  1.8G   1% /run
/dev/sr0        996M  996M     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      953M  953M     0 100% /rofs
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           8.8G  1.1M  8.8G   1% /tmp
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            8.8G   80K  8.8G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   56K  100M   1% /run/user
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /
9.7M    /bin
5.2M    /boot
12K     /dev
5.8M    /etc
30M     /home
275M    /lib
0   /lib64
0   /media
0   /mnt
0   /opt
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7004/task/7004/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7004/task/7004/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7004/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/7004/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
0   /proc
32K /root
du: cannot access ‘/run/user/999/gvfs’: Permission denied
1.5M    /run
18M /sbin
0   /srv
0   /sys
4.0K    /tmp
2.3G    /usr
155M    /var
995M    /cdrom
2.7G    /rofs
6.4G    /
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu :) Please refrain from just pasting large globs of text into a question.

Comment: Well David, in a post that I was reading before asking my question, I saw where one user asked the poster to please post the information that I did before any additional help could be offered. Just saving the time of the person willing to offer help.    ;O)

Comment: Please see the edit that has been made, It will be published soon. An actual question is helpful to answer or help you.

Comment: f you have gparted installed could you post a screen shot of the drive in question?

Comment: You've lost me here. The question is being able to add unused 17g partition from /sdb5 to /sda1 /boot. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: I've read that post. It doesn't explain how to merge partitions to create one larger partition, at least that I was able to read.

Comment: I'm looking for the button that allows me to add the screenshot so you can see it.

Comment: @DavidCole I'm not sure that you can add space from `/sdb` to `/sda`, can you explain how that might work?

Comment: @JamesReece What is the error message that you are getting indicating that your /boot is full?

Comment: sudo apt-get update says cannot complete update because /boot needs 84.3 mb additional space. I've already searched here for how to autoclean and autoremove, so that's done, but there just isn't enough space for additional updates. /sda is a 1tb partition with crypt-luks and GParted won't allow increasing /boot.

Comment: file:///home/ubuntu/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202015-12-18%2017:37:49.png

Comment: You can't merge unless the system was installed with LVM. And you definitely can't just drag-and-drop a filename into the comment section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for is physically impossible. You cannot move space from one drive (`/dev/sdb`) to another (`/dev/sda`).

Search AskUbuntu.com for "/boot full" answers.

**Warning** I detect, from the level of knowledge displayed in your question, a dangerous lack of understanding of how disks, disk partitions, filesystems, etc work. Please extend your education before you make **Any** changes. Also, make (and test) backups of everything you want to keep.

Just reinstalling with a bigger `/boot`, without learning how to manage `/boot` space just pushes the problem into the future.

Use `dpkg -S /boot/*` to see which packages own which files.

Comment: I've already backed up my installation, and yes, I am fairly new to linux, which is why I am here searching for answers. Now that I know that it is physically impossible, I will reformat, reinstall, and increase my /boot partition so this doesn't happen again.

Comment: Please help me improve my answers. What part of "Just reinstalling with a bigger `/boot`, without learning how to manage `/boot` space just pushes the problem into the future." was unclear?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience /boot tends to fill up with old kernel versions. Rather than trying to make the partition larger yo may want to look into how to get rid of the old kernels and thus free up space.

This is a place to start: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels